# UPDATE my_table doesn't work correctly

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm using the following query to replace old link with a new one:

```
UPDATE my_table SET file = 'link' WHERE my_table.file ='old_link';
```

In my tests I can't duplicate that and I'm not sure what's wrong with that query, but apparently sometimes it leaves the old entry and inserts a new one instead of updating!

mysql ver:
5.6.12-56 Percona Server, table type: innodb

Comment: How do you know that something else isn't actually inserting the “old one”?

Comment: I would almost say that is impossible. But let's keep it at 'improbable'. I guess it's more likely that you do an insert somewhere else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although an `UPDATE` won't fire an insert in its own, there could exist triggers in the database that would fire an `INSERT` whenever a record gets updated.

Here are some links that you should check:

- [CREATE TRIGGER Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-trigger.html)
- [Trigger Syntax and Examples](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/trigger-syntax.html)

Answer (score 3):

The query looks fine to me. `UPDATE` should never create new rows, only modify existing rows. The problem is probably in another part of the code.